# Android App Obfuscation (Webserver-Pinging | Data to get + save (MySQL))

Tags: java, security

Good evening,

I have a question in connection with my Android App. I want to add the stats of a player to my database. The problem is, I need to give a password in my source code and that's the problem! People can decompile my App and can connect to the databases and change things.

I want to obfuscate my plugins. So I decided to use ProGuards. Now the second problem is here: Proguard isn't obfuscating Strings. Also, if I would buy Stringer/ZKM. There are a lot of deobfuscators to deobfuscate this.
I do not know how to secure the app.

I could encrypt myself, but one time, it is decrypted, nothing is secure anymore.

Furthermore a PHP Post is also not secure. People are still be able to manipulate it.

What can I do to fix it?

Thank you!

Sincerely

Comment: You cannot. Your MySQL pasword will be always obtainable. Create layer between your app and database. Some type of rest service returning stats json. Or create database user, having granted only `stats` table for read only and use this user in app.

Comment: @Bedla How other developers are doing that? If I only do read-only, then I am not be able to add the stats to the server. And I think a layer can be manipulated by other developer, if they wanted to.

Comment: Common approach is to add service on server. During registration of user generate authorization token, associated with concrete user, return it, save it to app storage and into database. During persisting and obtaining stats send with every request this authorization token and on server side allow access only to those resources, associated with current authorization token (user).

Comment: Keep in mind that sending score in plaintext will allow user to fake his score using HTTP request. For this you need some hashing/encrypting algorithm, which will be more or less secure. Google for `two way encryption`, but always it will not be 100% bullet-proof, because salt for encryption is saved in APK. I hope somebody answers this, because the most of developers keeps their encryption under secret and there is no common/standard way of solving it (at least as I know).

Comment: Well, thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your app users have some sort of ID (probably e-mail and password?), use that from your app to identify a user, and fetch a token (typically a GUID) for that user. Keep a record of the token and it's validity status in your DB, so you can check it when the user tries to post or fetch his stats. You can specify that the token should only be valid for a certain amount of time, so that the user will have to provide his password again after the token has expired. For better security, you could require a new token for each particular request (that should help defend against replay-attacks, if that happens to be a relevant concern?)

Now you can keep the token in the app, and post it along with the stats whenever a user wants to communicate with your DB. You can do this via a POST to e.g. a Php page (or fetch data via a GET url). This way you can be fairly certain that the request is coming from a correctly identified user (at least if you're using HTTPS, which you should be doing anyway), and you are able to separate the App from communicating directly with the DB. Your service for doing this should obviously only provide the minimum necessary logic for storing and fetching stats for a specific (and identified!) user.

> "*Furthermore a PHP Post is also not secure. People are still be able to
>   manipulate it.*"

I assume what you want here, is to stop a user from posting fake stats from outside your app.

**In short, there is simply no way to do this securely, since what you are asking for is a way for a user to access an API, while simultaneously denying him or her access to that API, which is clearly a contradiction.**

Here's what you *can* do: Obscure your security-related logic to make circumventing it too much of a hassle for most people to bother doing so.

You might do this by including a key-value in your app (again, a GUID should do the trick), and require a hash of this key + the user's token to be passed along with each request. You could do this by

- Hard-coding a key into your app, which would require a user to decompile your app to access the key
- Fetching the key in a separate request, and updating it every now and then. This would mean a user could not find it by decompiling your code, but rather by replaying the request to get the code, just as your app does.
- A combination of the above two.

Another stumbling block you can add, is to include a check for the user-agent sending a request. If you make sure requests are only accepted if the user-agent matches that of your app, that should filter out requests from browsers and other applications. You could also look into the possibility of adding your own headers to further limit this.

All this really does is create a few more "hoops" that your users will have to jump through in order to create a fake request and have it reach your database. The more hassle you make for them, the less likely it is they will bother. Unfortunately, this also means more hassle for you as a developer when creating (and possibly maintaining) the app, and a motivated attacker will likely be able to get in anyway.

If you do experience such behavior, and you have the resources, then perhaps you can look for a better way to identify your users more explicitly (people are less likely to behave badly if they are unable to stay anonymous), and also to scan the requests and stats for anomalies. If you see completely unrealistic stats being posted, you can simply block the posting user.

In the end, this all boils down to striking a balance between the amount of trouble you feel you need to create for potential attackers, and the amount of work and resources you are willing to put down to do so.